# Space before ul/ol (HTML5, No CSS)

Tags: html

http://imgur.com/a/RWrIX

First picture is what it's suppose to look like, second is what I have. Apparently, this "space" can be removed without any CSS.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Lists</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Exercise on HTML5 Lists</h1>
        <dl>
            <dt>term 1 (definition list)</dt>
            <dd>term 1 description      
                <ol>
                    <li>ol list item 1</li>
                    <li>ol list item 2
                        <ul>
                            <li>ul list item 1</li>
                            <li>ul list item 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </dd>
            <dt>term 2 (definition list)</dt>
            <dd>term 2 description
                <ul>
                    <li>ul list item 3</li>
                    <li>ul list item 4
                        <ol>
                            <li>ol list item 3 </li>
                            <li>ol list item 4 </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                    <li>ul list item 5</li>
                    <li>ul list item 6</li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is doing what you want, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wo0mrnu6/) using FF

Comment: There's a default margin being set in the browser (Chrome and Safari specifically) of `1em`. So you'd have to use css to reset the top and bottom margin to 0.